# Required to set Array of Data as per Months get using mktime

Tags: laravel

First thanks to all who are helping us to solve the queries who had. I am self learner and new to Laravel working on home project.
I am trying to get the data for last 12 months and use the same in Table and chart. Data i am getting the Month and Total Amount.
I able to get Month for last 12 month using mktime also total amount from query.

Get Month for Last 12

```
$months = array();
                        for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                            $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') - $i, 1);
                            $months[date('n', $timestamp)] = date('M-Y', $timestamp);
                        }
```

Out Put is

```
array:12 [▼
       3 => "Mar-2022"
       2 => "Feb-2022"
       1 => "Jan-2022"
       12 => "Dec-2021"
       11 => "Nov-2021"
       10 => "Oct-2021"
       9 => "Sep-2021"
       8 => "Aug-2021"
       7 => "Jul-2021"
       6 => "Jun-2021"
       5 => "May-2021"
       4 => "Apr-2021"
```

Get total amount

```
$fiveincomedata    =   Dairyincome::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(milksaledate, "%M %Y") as "month_name", DATE_FORMAT(milksaledate,"%m") as "monthKey", SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount", max(milksaledate) as milksaledate'))
                      ->whereBetween('milksaledate', [$start_date, $end_date] )
                      ->groupBy('month_name','monthKey')
                      ->orderBy('milksaledate', 'desc')
                      ->get();
```

Output i am getting is

```
      array:4 [▼
               0 => array:4 [▼
               "month_name" => "March 2022"
               "monthKey" => "03"
               "totalamount" => "742.90"
               "milksaledate" => "2022-03-17"
              ]
               1 => array:4 [▼
               "month_name" => "February 2022"
               "monthKey" => "02"
               "totalamount" => "70.00"
               "milksaledate" => "2022-02-11"
              ]
               2 => array:4 [▼
               "month_name" => "December 2021"
               "monthKey" => "12"
               "totalamount" => "450.00"
               "milksaledate" => "2021-12-10"
               ]
              3 => array:4 [▼
               "month_name" => "November 2021"
               "monthKey" => "11"
               "totalamount" => "450.00"
               "milksaledate" => "2021-11-10"
               ]
              ]
```

Now i want to arrange the total amount array such a way which help me to use "array_combine" to combine both the array. I tried to use

```
$ddtest = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

                    foreach($fiveincomedata as $order)
                        {
                            $ddtest[$order->monthKey-1] = $order->totalamount;
                        }
```

But the monthkey is not matching.

Hope i explain my problem clearly and Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please update fiveincomedata query for get month number key to :

```
DATE_FORMAT(milksaledate,"%n") as "monthKey",
```

So, you will get month number without leading zeros. And in foreach it wil be array not object.

```
foreach($fiveincomedata as $order) 
{
   $ddtest[$order['monthKey']] = $order['totalamount'];
}
```

You will get below O/P:
[image]